# Distribution Strategy that leverages all CPUs and all GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I have mirrored distribution strategy defined below:

```
# create an instance of ImageDataGenerator
gen_train = ImageDataGenerator(
  rotation_range=20,
  width_shift_range=0.1,
  height_shift_range=0.1,
  shear_range=0.1,
  zoom_range=0.2,
  horizontal_flip=True,
  preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
)

gen_test = ImageDataGenerator(
  preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
)

batch_size = 512

# create generators
train_generator = gen_train.flow_from_directory(
  train_path,
  shuffle=True,
  target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
  batch_size=batch_size,
)
valid_generator = gen_test.flow_from_directory(
  valid_path,
  target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
  batch_size=batch_size,
)

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print(f'Number of devices: {strategy.num_replicas_in_sync}')
with strategy.scope():
    ptm = PretrainedModel(
        input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3],
        weights='imagenet',
        include_top=False)

    # freeze pretrained model weights
    ptm.trainable = False

    # map the data into feature vectors

    # Keras image data generator returns classes one-hot encoded

    K = len(folders) # number of classes
    x = Flatten()(ptm.output)
    x = Dense(K, activation='softmax')(x)

    # create a model object
    model = Model(inputs=ptm.input, outputs=x)

    # view the structure of the model
    model.summary()

    model.compile(
      loss='categorical_crossentropy',
      optimizer='adam',
      metrics=['accuracy']
    )

# fit the model
r = model.fit(
  train_generator,
  validation_data=valid_generator,
  epochs=10,
  steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(len(image_files) / batch_size)),
  validation_steps=int(np.ceil(len(valid_image_files) / batch_size)),
)
```

What I observe is,

1. the runtime does not change much if I don't use the strategy. If I have 4 GPU should I increase the batch size by 4?
2. The CPUs do not have full usage (GPUs have). Is there a distribution strategy that makes use of CPU fully?

Answer (score 0):

1. Batch size is global batch_size so you have to multiply your single batch sizer per num of GPUs
2. To do a better use of resources, you should use tf.data and read the performance guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance. Also you should read this: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training